# Bigcommerce Stencil display option pricing

Tags: product, bigcommerce, cornerstone

I am using the Cornerstone theme, the products in my store ave multiple optional extras available that can be added which when selected updates the product price - all works well.  However in order to let the customer know what the individual option costs is without them having to do maths these have to be listed in a table in the product description.  Is there a way to display the option price next to the option?

Comment: How about adding the price to the text of the option display name? For example: X-Large (+$2.00)

Comment: I too was surprised that it didn't work this way by default.

Comment: I can add it manually but there are over 600 products on the store so it would have been handy to have it automated in some way, you put the price in the rules and it automatically displays it.  Putting it in manually just gives another opportunity for potential error

Comment: This feature is in the planning stage at BigCommerce right now, so you might just want to wait until they add it.  I don't think you can do it yourself at this point with the data available to you.  https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/ideas#08713000000CBS9AAO